# How to efficiently get output nodes in a directed graph in networkx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I created a simple directed graph (DiGraph) in the Python network package `networkx`, like so:

```
import networkx as nx

G = DiGraph([(1, 2)])
```

**Now I would like to know the fastest / most efficient way to determine the output nodes** (which in this case is the node 2). By *output node* I mean nodes in the directed graph that have no successor - with *input nodes* being nodes that have no predecessor. The analogy is from Machine Learning, in which I am supplying values to the input nodes, perform mathematical operations on the edges and have *output values* in the *output nodes*. See [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Quan_Zheng8/publication/313741050/figure/fig1/AS:638008344707072@1529124451731/2D-directed-graph-for-a-neural-network-with-2-hidden-layers-Nodes-in-adjacent-layers-are.png) for an example, in which p, d and lambda are input nodes and p' and d' are output nodes.

After reading the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html) I came up with such inefficient methods as traversing all nodes of the graph, calling `successors()` on them and saving all nodes with no successor. This however is terribly inefficient, especially since the graph is obviously considerably larger and more complex in my actual project. I was hoping for a simple and efficient method such as `G.out_nodes()` or something similar that is keeping track of the output nodes when the graph is edited, though I seem to be unable to find it. However since determining output and input nodes in a directed graph is no uncommon task am I of the opinion that I am missing something. I was hoping that you might be able to help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by output nodes? Nodes with at least an incoming arc? Could you provide a better example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: By output nodes I mean nodes that have no successors in a directed graph. I may have taken over too much nomenclature from Machine Learning, but the following directed graph is [an example](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Quan_Zheng8/publication/313741050/figure/fig1/AS:638008344707072@1529124451731/2D-directed-graph-for-a-neural-network-with-2-hidden-layers-Nodes-in-adjacent-layers-are.png). p, d and lambda are input nodes. p' and d' are output nodes.

Comment: I will try to specify further in my original question. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your graph you could iterate and get the nodes with [`out_degree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_degree.html) equal to 0.

```
output_nodes = [u for u, deg in g.out_degree() if not deg]
```

However, you could get them directly when building your graph, indeed you could remove from the nodes `u` if `(u,v)` is an arc. The remaining will be output nodes.
Another possibility is to use another way to represent your graph according to size/most common operations to be applied.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though while this works is it not the efficient solution I was looking for as it seems only slightly better than the example I provided, which could have been expressed as ```[u for u in g.nodes() if len(list(g.successors(u))) == 0]```. In your solution am I still required to traverse through the whole graph. Maybe there is no more efficient functionality in networkx then...!?